# Qt QRubberBand selected in QTableView

Tags: qt, selected

I'm trying to select item in QTableView, but when I press and mouse move fast. Some item not select.
I'm using QRubberBand and overide MouseMove, MousePress,MouseRealse event:

Mouse Press Event :

```
void tableviewTest::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QTableView::mousePressEvent(event);
    mStartPoint = QPoint(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());
    mRubberBand->setGeometry (mStartPoint.x (), mStartPoint.y (), 0, 0);
    mRubberBand->show ();
}
```

Mouse Move Events:

```
void tableviewTest::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPoint movePoint = QPoint(event->pos ().x(), event->pos ().y ());
    mRubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(mStartPoint,movePoint).normalized());
    QRect rect = mRubberBand->geometry ();
    if (!rect.intersects (QRect(x,y,0,0))) {
            selectRow (indexAt (event->pos ()).row ());
    }
    this->viewport ()->update ();
    mRubberBand->update ();
    QTableView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Mouse Release Event:

```
void tableviewTest::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *inEvent)
{
    mRubberBand->hide();
    QTableView::mouseReleaseEvent(inEvent);
}
```

My question: How to select item when press and mouse move fast ? and If I wrong coding, please help me fix it.
Thanks all.

Comment: You should be more careful. What is the `rect.intersects(event)` intersects need QRect, not a event, edit your question and fix this please.

Comment: I run your code (not with qtableview subclass, but with event filter which is equivalent)and I could not reproduce problem, all items was selected, but I have very powerful CPU, maybe it is problem?Your computer can't process every mouseMoveEvent?

Comment: My computer has: Ram 4Gb, CPU core i5. If I move mouse slow, all items will be selected. But when i move mouse very fast, some item won't be choose.

P/s: I set Selection Behavior: SelectedRows and Selection Mode: ContigousSelection.